# Conditional matching and replace

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to replace titles from name which is appearing as below. But they are not in the same format always.

Sample data

```
AndrewMr
Simon Dr
AnjelaMiss
Robert
```

I have a list of titles in a separate temporary table

```
create table #T(Title varchar(10))
insert into #T
values ('Mr'),('Mrs'),('Ms'),('Miss'),('Mstr'),('Master'),('Dr'),('Captain'),('Hon'),('Prof'),('Lady'),
        ('Lord'),('Sir'),('Rev')
```

What I am trying to do is to remove any matching titles appearing in names

Manage to link it but not sure how to perform the replace

```
select  R.[First Name], right(R.[First Name],7), T.Title
from Temp R
     left outer join #T T on right(R.[First Name],7) like '%'+ t.Title + '%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all your examples, the match is only at the end.  So:

```
select R.[First Name],
       coalesce(rtrim(left(R.[First Name],
                           len(R.[First Name]) - len(t.Title)
                          )
                     ),
                R.[First Name]
               )
from Temp R left join
      #T T
      on R.[First Name] like '%' + t.Title;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ba6cf/4) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `R.[First Name] like '%' + t.Title`?

Comment: doesnt seems to work even after adding the missing square bracket. some syntax error it says `The left function requires 2 argument(s)`.

Comment: Should be `coalesce(left(R.[First Name], len(R.[First Name]) - len(t.Title)), R.[First Name])` according to the sql server docs. Not sure about the intent of the `rtrim` call though.

Comment: Hi Gordon, for some reason it doesnt match any. Please see [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ba6cf/3)

Comment: @user12073359 . . . Thank you for setting up the fiddle.  I fixed the code.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this Code Works Fine For your Case:

SELECT * ,REPLACE(T1.NAME,T2.TITLE,'')
FROM @TAB T1
LEFT JOIN #T T2 ON T1.NAME LIKE '%'+REPLACE(T2.TITLE,T1.NAME,'')+'%'

Comment: this is not doing a match at the end so will be problematic. also this will match Mrs to Mr as well